# Every non-compact Hermitian operator P has an infinite dimensional invariant subspace on which P is bounded from below

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I want an explanation of the following statement.

If $P$ is a Hermitian operator on Hilbert space and **not** compact, there exists an infinite-dimensional subspace $M$, invariant under $P$, on which $P$ is bounded from below.

I've thought about it for 2 days and still can't figure out why, I've thought about the definition of compact operator, spectral theorem, etc..

The above statement comes from [Halmos' problem book of Hilbert space](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=MK_aBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA292&dq=halmos+solution+176&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI87Sr7dWJxgIVhNmmCh2TUwB2#v=onepage&q=halmos%20solution%20176&f=false), solution 176.

Could anyone understand this explain this to me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One can begin by proving the following lemma :

---

For each $\epsilon > 0$, define
$$
\Delta_{\epsilon} := \{z\in \sigma(P) : |z| > \epsilon\}
$$
and set
$$
E_{\epsilon} := \chi_{\Delta_{\epsilon}}(P)
$$

> Claim: $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $E_{\epsilon}$ is not compact.

Proof: Suppose $E_{\epsilon}$ is compact for all $\epsilon > 0$, then consider
$$
P - PE_{\epsilon} = f_{\epsilon}(P) \text{ where } f_{\epsilon}(z) = z-z\chi_{\Delta_{\epsilon}}(z) = z\chi_{\sigma(P)\setminus \Delta_{\epsilon}}(z)
$$
Hence
$$
\|P - PE_{\epsilon}\| \leq \epsilon
$$
and so $P$ is a limit of compact operators which is compact. This is a contradiction.

---

By the above lemma, $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that
$$
Q := \chi_{\Delta_{\epsilon}}(P)
$$
is non-compact, and hence an infinite rank projection. Note that $PQ = QP$, so the range space $M$ of $Q$ is an invariant subspace under $P$.

Comment: Sorry, it's not very clear to me what $E_\epsilon$ and its range space are. Why is $E_\epsilon$ a projection and why is $P$ bounded from below on the range space $M$ of $Q$. $E_\epsilon$ is a charactersitc function of operators, so its domain is set of operatos, and its range is also set of operators, am i right?

Comment: $E_{\epsilon}$ is a projection since it is obtained by applying a characteristic function to $P$. A characteristic function is a projection, and the Borel functional calculus is a $\ast$-homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Since $P$ is Hermitian, it satisfies the Spectral Theorem:
$$
P=\int_{\sigma(P)}\lambda\,dE(\lambda),
$$
for a spectral measure $E$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\sigma(P)$.

The fact that $P$ is not compact implies that there exists $\lambda_0\in\sigma(P)$, $\lambda_0\ne0$, such that it is an eigenvalue with infinite multiplicity, or accumulation point for $\sigma(P)$.

The easy case occurs when $\lambda_0$ is an eigenvalue with infinite multiplicity. In this case $E(\{\lambda_0\})$ is an infinite-dimensional subspace, and
$$
P\,E(\{\lambda_0\})=\int_{\sigma(P)}\lambda\,1_{\{\lambda_0\}}\,dE(\lambda)=\lambda_0\,E(\{\lambda_0\}).
$$
So, if $\xi$ is in the range of $E(\{\lambda_0\})$, we have
$$
\|P\xi\|=\|P\,E(\{\lambda_0\})\xi\|=\|\lambda_0\,E(\{\lambda_0\})\xi\|=|\lambda_0|\,\|\xi\|
$$
and $P$ is bounded below on the range of $E(\{\lambda_0\})$.

When $\lambda_0$ is not an eigenvalue but an accumulation point of $\sigma(P)$, we repeat the argument above replacing the set $\{\lambda_0\}$ with  $(\lambda_0-\delta,\lambda_0+\delta)$ for $\delta $ small enough so that  the interval does $\int _{|\lambda|\geq\varepsilon }\lambda\,dE (\lambda) $ not touch zero.

Comment: Why is that if $P$ is not compact, then there exists nonzero $\lambda_0 \in \sigma (P)$ such that it is an eigenvalue with infinite multilplicity, or accumilation point for $\sigma (P)$ ?

Comment: Because if $P $ is selfadjoint,  every nonzero eigenvalue has finite multiplicity, and the only accumulation point of the spectrum is zero, then $ P $  is compact.

Comment: I still don't get, this is just the contrapositive of the previous statement, but why is it true? I've never learned that, could you explain a little more?

Comment: I know every nonzero eigenvalue of a compact operator has finite multiplicity, and zero is the only possible accumulation point of the spectrum of a compact operator, but I don't know why if in addition, the compact operator is self-adjoint, then converse  true.

Comment: It's the Spectral Theorem. In the case as I said, $\int _{|\lambda|\geq\varepsilon }\lambda\,dE (\lambda) $ is finite-rank, and $\int _{|\lambda|<\varepsilon }\lambda\,dE (\lambda) $  has norm at most $\varepsilon  $, so $P $ is a limit of finite-rank operators.

Comment: OK, I got it, thank you for your help

Comment: My pleasure. $ $